# Qual o comportamento de um método que retorna inteiro dentro do if?

Tags: java, lógica

Tenho o seguinte código para teste (linguagem Java):

```
public class Teste {
static int n = 10;
static int[] vB = new int[10];


public static void exibir(){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.print(" " + vB[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
}

public static int remover(int chave){
    if (n == 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (vB[i] == chave) {

            if (i != (n-1)) { //se não for o último item
                for (int k = i; k < (n-1); k++) {
                    vB[k] = vB[k+1]; //vetor caminha
                }
            }
            n--;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int valor = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        vB[i] = valor;
        valor += 2; 
    }

    exibir();

    System.out.println("remover(19) = "+remover(19));
    if (remover(19) == -1) {
        System.out.println("O vetor vB está vazio!");
    } else if(remover(19) == 1){
        System.out.println("Sucesso! A chave 19 foi removida do vetor vB.");
    } else if(remover(19) == 0){
        System.out.println("A chave 19 não foi encontrada no vetor vB.");
    }

    n++;
    System.out.println("");

    int b = remover(19);
    System.out.println("b = "+b);
    if (b == -1) {
        System.out.println("O vetor vB está vazio!");
    } else if(b == 1){
        System.out.println("Sucesso! A chave 19 foi removida do vetor vB.");
    } else if(b == 0){
        System.out.println("A chave 19 não foi encontrada no vetor vB.");
    }

}
}
```

A saída é:

```
 run:
 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19

 remover(19) = 1
 A chave 19 não foi encontrada no vetor vB.

 b = 1
 Sucesso! A chave 19 foi removida do vetor vB.
```

Em ambos os casos, remover(19) retorna 1.
Porém, quando o retorno do método não é atribuído a uma variável int, ele retorna um valor diferente do esperado (esperado por mim), que seria: 
"Sucesso! A chave 19 foi removida do vetor vB."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe esse trecho:

```
    System.out.println("remover(19) = "+remover(19));
    if (remover(19) == -1) {
        System.out.println("O vetor vB está vazio!");
    } else if(remover(19) == 1){
        System.out.println("Sucesso! A chave 19 foi removida do vetor vB.");
    } else if(remover(19) == 0){
        System.out.println("A chave 19 não foi encontrada no vetor vB.");
    }
```

No primeiro `System.out`, ele remove o número 19. No `if`, ele tenta remover o 19 outra vez, e como não acha (porque já removeu antes) e resulta em 0, ele não entra no bloco do `if` e cai no primeiro `else`. Nesse `else`, ele tenta remover uma terceira vez, e como não encontra (resulta em 0), ele cai no último `else`. Ele então tenta remover uma quarta vez e como dessa vez o resultado novamente é 0, ele mostra a mensagem.

Em resumo, esse código que está aí é equivalente a isso:

```
    int resultado1 = remover(19);
    System.out.println("remover(19) = " + resultado1);

    int resultado2 = remover(19);
    if (resultado2 == -1) {
        System.out.println("O vetor vB está vazio!");
    } else {
        int resultado3 = remover(19);
        if (resultado3 == 1) {
            System.out.println("Sucesso! A chave 19 foi removida do vetor vB.");
        } else {
            int resultado4 = remover(19);
            if (resultado4 == 0) {
                System.out.println("A chave 19 não foi encontrada no vetor vB.");
            }
        }
    }
```

O problema é que você está chamando `remover(19)` várias vezes no `if`. Você deveria chamar apenas uma. O que você quer é isso:

```
    int resultado = remover(19);
    System.out.println("remover(19) = " + resultado);
    if (resultado == -1) {
        System.out.println("O vetor vB está vazio!");
    } else if (resultado == 1) {
        System.out.println("Sucesso! A chave 19 foi removida do vetor vB.");
    } else if (resultado == 0) {
        System.out.println("A chave 19 não foi encontrada no vetor vB.");
    }
```

E é exatamente isso que você faz no bloco seguinte mais abaixo.

Comment: Putz... Tô precisando dormir um pouco... Que coisa boba... Valeu Victor!!

Comment: @JoãoPauloRolim Se não lhe resta mais nenhuma dúvida acerca desta pergunta, clique no ✅ que aparece abaixo do número de votação desta resposta (ou da outra se você assim preferir) para marcá-la como aceita e marcar a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda tiver alguma dúvida, sinta-se livre para comentar. Foi um prazer ajudá-lo. 

Answer (score 2):

Quando não atribui o retorno do método a uma variável, como aqui:

```
System.out.println("remover(19) = "+remover(19));
if (remover(19) == -1) {
    System.out.println("O vetor vB está vazio!");
} else if(remover(19) == 1){
    System.out.println("Sucesso! A chave 19 foi removida do vetor vB.");
} else if(remover(19) == 0){
    System.out.println("A chave 19 não foi encontrada no vetor vB.");
}
```

Acontece que está a chamar o remover potencialmente 4 vezes, dependendo do valor que devolve.

É primeiro chamado no `System.out`:

```
System.out.println("remover(19) = "+remover(19));
```

E logo de seguida chamado no `if`:

```
if (remover(19) == -1) {
```

E neste caso como o elemento já foi removido vai dar `0` que não encontrou o valor no vetor, e vai continuar a chamar nos outros ifs até acertar no ultimo, que é o resultado apresentado quando o programa é executado:

> 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19
>
> remover(19) = 1
>
> A chave 19 não foi encontrada no vetor vB.

Neste tipo de situações a forma como foi feito no segundo bloco é exatamente o que se pretende:

```
int b = remover(19);
System.out.println("b = "+b);
if (b == -1) {
    System.out.println("O vetor vB está vazio!");
} else if(b == 1){
    System.out.println("Sucesso! A chave 19 foi removida do vetor vB.");
} else if(b == 0){
    System.out.println("A chave 19 não foi encontrada no vetor vB.");
}
```

Guardando assim o resultado numa variável garantido que apenas a usa e não volta a chamar o mesmo método varias vezes.